# game int changes on input and does not evaluate what i set it to

Tags: python

game_2 is = 34 but changes when the input from guess, how
do i keep it as 34?? as it keeps saying error how do i
make this more readable and is there anything i can do to
not make the input change the answer?

```
my_name = 'shaun'
yourname = input('what is your name? ')
print('nice to meet you', yourname, 'i am', my_name)
play_game = input('do you want to play a game? ')
if play_game == 'yes':
    print('okay lets play a game')
else:
    print('okay, bye then')
    quit()
game = input(f'if you can tell me how old you are, i have to work out how many months that is, and then its your turn to do it to me... okay ' + yourname +"? ")
if game == 'yes' or 'okay' or 'go on then' or 'yeah':
    print('okay, how old are you in years? ')
    age = int(input())
    answer = age * 12
    print("that's way to easy ", answer)
    game_2 = 34
    guess = input('guess my age, i will give you a clue, i am 408 months old ')
    if guess == game_2:
        print("wow!! you're a wizard! " + yourname)
    else:
        print('no, try again ' + yourname)
        input()
        print("nope, not even close")
        input()
        print('come on, are you even trying?, last go ')
        input()
        print(' my age was 34 okay maybe this is to ward for you, shall we try another game?')
```

Comment: input returns string. either make game_2 = "34" or cast your input into int

Comment: `input()` returns a string, you did it correctly here: `age = int(input())`, but not on `guess = input('guess ...')`

Comment: I've tried to fix the formatting, but might have messed up the indentation and since this is python: please check that this is still what you meant, coder1996.

Comment: `game == 'yes' or 'okay' or 'go on then' or 'yeah'` is not what you intended (always evaluates to `*okay'` which is truthy); use `game in {'yes', 'okay', 'go on then', 'yeah'}` instead to check whether the user chose one of your options.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki hi, i did this but didnt work

Comment: @coder1996 what did you do and how did it not work?